# Inheritance In Default Constructor Definition

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I've been learning about Design Patterns and in my implementations of Strategy Design Pattern I discovered that I couldn't declare inheritance in a class definition like so:

```
class Context
{
private:
    Strategy *strategy_;
public:
    Context(Strategy* strategy) : strategy_(strategy); // This line
    ~Context();
    void set_strategy(Strategy* strategy);
    void DoStuff() const;
};
```

By changing the default constructor to be within my class definition worked fine

```
Context(Strategy* strategy=nullptr) : strategy_(strategy){}
```

Or by removing the inheritance from the definition and defining it outside the class like so.

```
class Context
{
private:
    Strategy *strategy_;
public:
    Context(Strategy* strategy); // This line
    ~Context();
    void set_strategy(Strategy* strategy);
    void DoStuff() const;
};

Context::Context(Strategy *strategy=nullptr) : strategy_(strategy){} // and this line
```

I'm curious as to why inheritance can't be declared in the default constructor within the class definition.

Comment: You cannot write inheritance in constructors. What you wrote is [member initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor).

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that has anything to do with inheritance?

Comment: Not sure if this is even a tangent, but something like `m_strategy` makes picking members out of a list a lot easier for you and the IDE/editor.

Comment: Is this an example of an operator being overloaded, is there way to use ':' for inheritance? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ClockworkKettle : is not an operator in either case. It's just part of the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write one of:
`Context(Strategy* strategy) : strategy_(strategy) {}` or `Context(Strategy* strategy);` in your class declaration.

That colon doesn't indicate inheritance at all *here*, but direct member initialization. It's a very good thing to use in C++ and I highly recommend it. But you use it when you are implementing the constructor.

Inheritance is done on the class itself:
`class Foo : public Bar {}; // class Foo inherits Bar publicly`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, but you've totally got it wrong. Whatever you're not doing its not inheritance at all.

Strategy design pattern is about composition. You're using composition to create strategy design pattern which is done in your code by keeping a pointer like "Strategy *strategy_" which points to a Strategy object. So, it would be right to say, you're using composition.

If there is a class A which inherits class B, in cpp we write as follows:

```
class A {
  // private variables write here
  int x_, y_;
  // private methods
  void somePrivateMethod() {
  }
public:
  // public variable write here
  int x, y;
  // public methods
  A() {
  }
  void somePublicMethod() {
  }
}

class B : public A {
  int u, v, w;
public:
  int z;
  B() {
  }
  void someMethodInB() {
  }
}
```

And for more about cpp inheritance, I would suggest you to have a look at **Herbert Schild's** book **CPP: The complete reference** books *inheritance* chapter.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Will try get my hands on a copy.